# Control Servo with Galileo MRAA for Node

Tags: node.js, hardware, intel-galileo

I've got an intel galileo I'm trying to control with Node.js, but I'm coming across a few problems. The library I'm using has examples for changing binary and/or analog values of pins, but nothing specific about controlling servo motors. The code I have currently is as follows.

```
var B = 3975;
var mraa = require("mraa");
var servo = new mraa.Aio(1);//connects to the servo
```

The thing is, I have no idea how to control the servo, and the documentation for MRAA is almost nonexistant. Has anyone here done something similar before and would be able to help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Servos typically use PWM (Pulse-Width Modulation) control. You should connect the servo control line to one of the digital pins marked with '~' sign. That sign tells that the pin will generate PWM data. Then google your servo type to learn the PWM parameters it accepts. You can then follow the mraa PWM examples to set suitable values to the PWM pin.

Answer (score 0):

PWM Example for mraa on (Edison but will  work on Galileo but period should be 62500)

```
mraa = require('mraa');
servo = new m.Pwm(3);//Pin 3
servo.enable(true);
servo.period_us(19000000) //PWM Period https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM
servo.write(1);
sleep(1000);
servo.write(0);
sleep(1000);
servo.write(0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

To control a servo , you send to it an Pulse width modulated signal, which is a signal that is periodic ,i.e repeats itself. Each period, i.e, the time between a point of the signal and the its repetition, consists of two parts : on and off. the on is a high voltage(for example equal to bias voltage), and the off is low voltage (for example equal to 0 Volt). The period has a time which is the period time, its reciprocal is the frequency. The ratio between on time to the off time is called duty cycle, duty cycle ranges from 0.0 to 1.0. The servo motor rotates only till it reaches an angle corresponding to the duty cycle and stops.

Before anything here is the link to mraa node.js documentation:
https://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/node/

And a note to say: mraa is a low level framework, so if this is your first time with using a servo , i would recommend you delay using mraa to later and use CylonJS first, a tutorial for controlling a servo using CylonJS on Intel Edison which is fairly similar to Intel Galileo is at: 
http://slideplayer.com/slide/7959041/
This a very nice example that I ran before on Intel Edison kit.

That said, once you are finished with this tutorial and want to try servo in mraa node.js, here is a tutorial to rotate the servo till you press Ctrl-C to end the program. It starts the duty cycle at 0, increments it till 1 and then decrements till 0, and loops again. This code is a translation of the C code at
https://navinbhaskar.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/cc-on-intel-edisongalileo-part3-pwm/ and i did not test the translation.

```
/*translation of C++ code at
 https://navinbhaskar.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/cc-on-intel-edisongalileo-part3-pwm/
mraa node.js documentation at:
https://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/node/
*/
"use strict";


const mraa = require("mraa");
const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

const  PWM_PIN  =   5 ;       /**< The pin where the LED is connected */

var keepRunning= false;

///** Signal handler used to stop this application cleanly */
/* 
     * Associate ctrl+c with our handler that clears the 'keepRunning'
     * flag that allows us to stop the PWM when exiting 
     */
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    keepRunning = false;
});

//Step 1: Initialize the mraa system

var result =mraa.init();
if(result == mraa.Result.SUCCESS)
    console.log("mraa initialization succeded.");
else
    console.log("mraa initializtion failed.")

/* Step2: Initialize D5 for PWM operation */
var pwm_interface = mraa.PWM;

var owner =true;
var chipid= 1;
pwm_interface.Pwm(PWM_PIN,owner,chipid);
 /*
     * Control the period with "mraa_pwm_period_us"
     *
     *       +----------------+                +----------------+                |
     *       |                |                |                |                |
     *       |                |                |                |                |
     *       |                |                |                |                |
     *       |                |                |                |                |
     *       |                |                |                |                |
     *       |                |                |                |                |
     *       |                |                |                |                |
     *       |                |                |                |                |
     *       +                +----------------+                +----------------+
     *       ^                                 ^
     *       |                                 |
     *       |<---------- Period ------------->|
     *       |               ^                 |
     *       |               |                 |
     *                       | 
     *      pwm_interface.period_us( 5000);
     */

   /* Step3: Set the period on the PWM pin */
   const PWM_Period_in_microseconds=5000;
    pwm_interface.period_us( PWM_Period_in_microseconds);      // Set the period as 5000 us or 5ms

    /* Step4: Enable the PWM pulse on the pin */
    var pwm_enabling_result= pwm_interface.enable(true);

    var delta = 0.05;   /* Variation on the duty cycle */
    var duty = 0.0;       /* 0% duty cycle */
    keepRunning = true;
    const sleep_duration_in_Microsecond=50000;

 while (keepRunning){
        if (duty >= 1)
        {
            duty = 1;          // Intensity of LED at highest 
            delta = -0.05;     // Need to decrease the duty cycle
        }
        else if (duty <= 0)
        {
            duty = 0;          // Intensity of LED at the lowest
            delta = +0.05;     // Need to increase the duty cycle 
        }
       /*
        *  Control the duty cycle with "write"
        *    +------+                            +------+                            
        *    |      |                            |      |                           
        *    |      |                            |      |                           
        *    |      |                            |      |                           
        *    |      |                            |      |                           
        *    |      |                            |      |                           
        *    |      |                            |      |                           
        *    |      |                            |      |                           
        *    |      |                            |      |                           
        *    +      +----------------------------+      +---------------------------+
        *    ^      ^
        *    |      |
        *    |<---->|
        *        ^
        *        |-----------------
        *                          |
        *  pwm_interface.write( 0.2);
        * 
        */

     /* Step5: Use the function 'mraa_pwm_write' to set the duty cycle */
    pwm_interface.write( duty);
    /* Wait for some time */
    var sleep = spawnSync('usleep', [sleep_duration_in_Microsecond]);

    duty = duty + delta;
}

    /* Step6: Stop the PWM when not required */
    pwm_interface.enable(false);
```